# Disable input (no2) if input (no1) is empty

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="year" autofocus onkeypress='validate(event)'><br>
<input type="text" name="month" onkeypress='validate(event)'><br>
```

JavaScript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }}
</script>
```

How to disable (prevent to write numbers in the textbox) input (name "month") if my input (name "year") is empty? And of course how to enable (allow to write number) it if i will type a year?

Comment: You can toggle between `style.display="none"` and `style.display=""` `if(document.getElementById("year").style.display=="";){document.getElementById("year").style.display=="none";}`

Comment: thx, but where i have to write this script? in my validate(evt) function? or i have to create new?

Comment: `"mounth"`? Nice typo :p

Comment: You can put it in your validate function, just add a check to see if the element is empty before hiding/showing.  Also, if you just wanted to disable, you could do `document.getElementById("year").disabled=true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that is very similar to @prabeen giri's:

HTML needs to be slightly modified as follows:

```
<form>
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="year" autofocus="autofocus" onkeypress="javascript:validate(event);"><br>
  <input type="text" id='monthinput' name="mounth" onkeypress='javascript:validate(event)' disabled="true"><br>
 </div>
</form>
```

And then we add code to grab the month input, and set the 'disabled' attribute. We can remove the `evt.preventDefault()` code because we want people to be able to type.

```
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event,
      regex    = /[0-9]|\./,
      monthel  = document.getElementById('monthinput'),
      key      = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  if ( !regex.test(key) ) {
      monthel.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
      monthel.removeAttribute('disabled', "");
  }
}
```

I have actually tested this, and it does work. However, if you're more interested in showing/hiding the input depending on whether it's valid, I've written a [jQuery plugin that makes showing/hiding form sections easy](http://plugins.jquery.com/dependent-questions/). Obviously it requires jQuery though.

Answer (score 0):

Set the month input disabled by default because I believe initially year will have empty value

`<input type="text" name="mounth" onkeypress='validate(event)' disabled='disabled'>`

Now write the blur and keypress events handlers

```
var month_input = document.getElementById('month'); 
var year_input = document.getElementById("year"); 
year_input.onblur = function(){ 
 if (this.value == '') { 
   month_input.setAttribute('disabled',true); 
 } 
}
year_input.onkeypress = function(){ 
  if (this.value!= ''){ 
    month_input.setAttribute('disabled',false); 
  } 
}
```

I am not sure if `onblur` will work because I am confused if it to work , we may need `onfocus` event handler too. I have not tested it !!

Comment: thx, but it doesn't work ;/ input(name "month") is always disabled